# Does Mod_Rewrite support Named Capturing Groups

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

Does `mod_rewrite` support [Named Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)? Please support your reply with an example if it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jey Keu,

They are not available in Apache mod_rewrite but you can use them in most other modern regular expression engines support capturing groups, which are numbered from left to right.